Using einsum for transpose times matrix times transpose: x@A@x^T
So I have m number of different vectors (say x), each one is (1,n), stacked horizontally, totally in a (m,n) matrix we call it B, and a matrix (A) with dimension (n,n).
I want to compute xAx^T for all vectors x, output should be (m,1)
How can I write an einsum query for this given B and A?
Here is a sample without einsum:
    import torch
    m = 30
    n = 4
    B = torch.randn(m, n)
    A = torch.randn(n, n)
    result = torch.zeros(m,1)
    for i in range(m):
        x = B[i].unsqueeze(0)
        result[i] = torch.matmul(x, torch.matmul(A, x.T))


Can you write an example of the desired behavior using a loop?

@NickODell Done.

Using einsum and tensordot :
import torch
import numpy as np

A = torch.tensor([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0],
                  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0]])

B = torch.tensor([[1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 10.0],
                  [2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0],
                  [3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0]])

# Using einsum

res_using_einsum = torch.einsum('bi,ij,bj -> b',B,A,B).unsqueeze(dim = -1)
print(res_using_einsum)
'''
tensor([[580.],
        [730.],
        [900.]])
'''

# Using tensordot

BA = torch.tensordot(B, A, dims = ([1],[0]))
'''
BA :
tensor([[ 1.,  8., 21., 40.],
        [ 2., 10., 24., 44.],
        [ 3., 12., 27., 48.]])
'''
res_using_tensordot = torch.tensordot(BA, B, dims =([1],[1]))#.unsqueeze(-1)

'''
res_using_tensordot :

tensor([[580., 650., 720.],
        [650., 730., 810.],
        [720., 810., 900.]])
'''
diagonal_result = torch.diagonal(res_using_tensordot, 0).unsqueeze(1)
'''
tensor([[580.],
        [730.],
        [900.]])

'''


With a (m,n) and (n,n)
res = np.einsum('ij,jk,lk-il', B,A,B)

should produce a (m,m) array.
'ij,jk,ik->i' should make (m,)
With matmul/@ I think these will produce
B@A@(B.T) # (m,m)

B[:,None,:]@A@B[:,:,None] # (m,1,1)

I'm posting from my phone, so can't test these right now.

This is the equivalent of that loop:
result_einsum = torch.einsum('ki,ij,kj->k', B, A, B)[..., None]

The [..., None] part exists to add the extra dimension to the output. Couldn't figure out how to do that with pure einsum, though the extra part is at least zero-copy.
